# How does one obtain a type III ANOVA output for a GEE?

Tags: regression, anova, glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

ANOVA types I, II and III are explained [here](https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/).  For GLMM and GEE differences see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21613/what-is-the-difference-between-glm-and-gee).  I am using the anova() function in geepack to determine the overall impact of several categorical variable in a GEE.  This package can only run type I ANOVA.  I was wondering if there is another package that can generate a similar output but using a type III ANOVA method.  I know the package car can do this for GLMM, but not for a GEE.

Comment: What makes type III tests appropriate?  Type III = U.S. Senate.  Type II = U.S. House of Representatives.  It's often not logical for all categories of X to have the same weight regardless of their population.

Answer (score 1):

The [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/confidence-intervals.html#joint_tests) package provides a Type III output for `geepack` models.

Comment: For models supported by the *emmeans* package, see:  [cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html)