# Getting the variance-covariance matrix of regression coefficients in GEE

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

I fitted a GEE model using the function `genZcor` with user defined
correlation matrix. I want to get the var-cov matrix of the regression
coefficients. But the output provides only limited information.

I would be very much thankful if you could kindly let me know how to get
it since I am struggling lot getting this.

Answer (score 8):

The naive VC matrix of the parameter estimates is stored in the `vbeta.naiv` component of the GEE fit.

Here is an illustration with the Ohio data:

```
library(geepack)
data(ohio)
fm <- resp ~ age*smoke
gee.fit <- geese(fm, id=id, data=ohio, family=binomial, 
                 corstr="exch", scale.fix=TRUE)
summary(gee.fit)
```

This is a basic model where the working correlation is considered symmetric with correlation $\rho$. Here, the within-cluster correlation is estimated at $\hat\rho=0.355$. Estimates with robust standard error (computed from a sandwich estimator, as detailed in the [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v15/i02/paper), pp. 4-5) are shown below:

```
            estimate  san.se     wald       p
(Intercept) -1.90050 0.11909 254.6860 0.00000
age         -0.14124 0.05820   5.8889 0.01524
smoke        0.31383 0.18784   2.7912 0.09478
age:smoke    0.07083 0.08828   0.6438 0.42234
```

The robust and naive VC matrices are obtained as follows:

```
> gee.fit$vbeta
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.014182  0.002677 -0.014182 -0.002677
[2,]  0.002677  0.003387 -0.002677 -0.003387
[3,] -0.014182 -0.002677  0.035285  0.005348
[4,] -0.002677 -0.003387  0.005348  0.007793
> gee.fit$vbeta.naiv
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.01407  0.002400 -0.014072 -0.002400
[2,]  0.00240  0.003139 -0.002400 -0.003139
[3,] -0.01407 -0.002400  0.034991  0.005373
[4,] -0.00240 -0.003139  0.005373  0.007938
```

We can check that the Wald statistics computed using those values (as the ratio of the estimates to their standard errors, which are the diagonal entries of the VC matrix) match the ones displayed in the summary table:

```
> (gee.fit$beta/sqrt(diag(gee.fit$vbeta)))^2
(Intercept)         age       smoke   age:smoke 
   254.6860      5.8889      2.7912      0.6438
```

(If you use `geeglm` instead, coefficients are available through the accessor `coef()`, and the robust VC matrix is stored in `gee.fit$geese$vbeta` where `gee.fit` now holds the results of the call to `geeglm`.)

A more detailed account of GEE computing is available in this excellent tutorial, [Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE)](https://web.archive.org/web/20070621134222/http://gbi.agrsci.dk/statistics/courses/phd07/material/Day10/gee-lecture.pdf), by Søren Højsgaard and Ulrich Halekoh.

Comment: I am trying to perform Tukey-type comparison using the glht package after fitting a GEE model. To do this I have to specify the vcov matrix in the glht function, which lead me to this post... Now, the problem is that the robust elements in the vcov matrix are smaller than the naive elements. Do you have inkling or former experience as to how this can be?