# Interpreting coefficients of ordinal logistic regression when there is clustering within the data

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations, ordered-logit

I have built and refined a regression model using the `ordinal` package in `R`. The measure is $0>1>2>3>4>5$ (Yes/No questions) and is repeated every 10 minutes for an hour (episode) within the same person, twice a week for up to 6 weeks, but average 3 weeks. I have 6000 such observations on 1000 hours for 150 people.

When I built a univariate model using number of questions $(0-5)$ answered as the dependent variable and say, Gender as the independent variable, with random intercepts for person and episode I interpreted the coefficients as "Difference in the proportional log-odds of one extra question being answered on average over all timepoints".

My question is: Is that valid, or have I made unsupportable assumptions due to the nature of the mixed effects model for which I am not accounting.

Incidentally I can completely recommend the "ordinal" package, although it is in development, and has minor difficulties with convergence for some unstandardised parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Before answering your question, it is worthwhile to note the difference between individual specific and population averaged models for clustered data, since they are each interpreted differently:

- Individual specific models explicitly model the dependence at the individual level (e.g. by using [random effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model)). In these models the regression coefficients are interpreted as: **the increase in an *individual's* average response for a one unit increase in the predictor** - this sounds like the type of model you'd ideally fit but cannot.
- Population average models (e.g. [GEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation)) average over the individual/group level perturbations to produce an estimate of the population average effect that "adjusts" for the dependence, in some sense. So, the regression coefficients are interpreted as **the increase in an *population* average response for a one unit increase in the predictor** - this sounds like the type of model you did fit.

The two interpretations are only equivalent in *linear* mixed effects models since averaging over the random effects on a transformed scale (e.g. logistic) does not, in general, produce mean 0 perturbations on the original scale of the data. For more discussion of this difference [see my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-to-use-generalized-estimating-equations-vs-mixed-effects-models/16415#16415).

Now to answer your question -- the regression model you have fit assumes independence between units and can be conceived of as a GEE model with a working independence correlation structure. By not modeling the dependencies at the individual level, you've effectively averaged over the random effects. Therefore, the interpretation you've given is not unsupportable - the coefficients should be interpreted as the population average change in the log-odds of one extra question being answered (which is pretty close to what you've written), not the expected change in an individual's log-odds of one extra question being answered (you'd need a mixed model to estimate that parameter).

**Edit:** I've only given commentary on *interpretation* of your point estimates. One should note that if you've just used the $p$-values produced from an ordinary ordinal logistic regression model, then your inference may be biased. You may want to consider using a bootstrap procedure or deriving robust Huber-White sandwich standard errors for your model to get approximately unbiased confidence intervals and $p$-values.