# Why is a logistic regression model using glm() different from a linear model with a logit transformation of the response using lm()?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I've only just started learning logistic regression so bear with me. As I understand it, the logistic regression model is as follows:

$$\log\left(\frac{p(X)}{1-p(X)}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X $$

where p(X) = the proportion of successes.

Please tell if I'm wrong but isn't the logistic regression model effectively a linear regression model with a logit link transformation of the binomial response?

I ran into a problem when I was playing around with a data frame.
I'm trying to fit a logistic regression model to a data set with two explanatory variables, water (binary) & concentration (continuous) and a binomial response variable (no. of successes from no. of trials).

```
    > trout_new
   Concentration Water Total Successes       prop      logit
47          2880     0   143       105 0.73426573  1.0163742
5            180     1    68         4 0.05882353 -2.7725887
7            180     1   109        11 0.10091743 -2.1870722
41          1440     0   100        14 0.14000000 -1.8152900
35           360     0    61         1 0.01639344 -4.0943446
34           360     0   145        21 0.14482759 -1.7757591
44          1440     0   113         3 0.02654867 -3.6018681
39           720     0    99        40 0.40404040 -0.3886580
4             90     1   122         9 0.07377049 -2.5301632
14           720     1    87         3 0.03448276 -3.3322045
11           360     1   129         9 0.06976744 -2.5902672
17          1440     1   140        60 0.42857143 -0.2876821
```

Column `prop` is the proportion of successes to Total and column `logit` is the log odds of success which was calculated as `log(prop/(1-prop))`.

I fit a logistic regression model as such:

```
> trout_model <- glm(cbind(Successes,Total-Successes) ~ Water + 
                            Concentration, family =  binomial, 
                            data = trout_new)
> summary(trout_model)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(Successes, Total - Successes) ~ Water + 
          Concentration, 
    family = binomial, data = trout_new)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-6.9030  -2.4959  -0.5221   1.5977   6.8773  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.820e+00  1.856e-01 -15.193   <2e-16 ***
Water          2.404e-01  1.728e-01   1.391    0.164    
Concentration  1.245e-03  9.557e-05  13.029   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 375.75  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 141.66  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 195.51

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Then I fit a linear model to log odds of successes, I tried glm(..., family = gaussian) and lm().

```
> trout_model1 <- glm(logit~Water + Concentration, 
                      family = gaussian, data = trout_new)
> summary(trout_model1)

Call:
glm(formula = logit ~ Water + Concentration, family = gaussian, 
    data = trout_new)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.12774  -0.57066   0.08564   0.70799   1.99285  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -3.2888858  0.8145197  -4.038  0.00294 **
Water          0.3817345  0.8213712   0.465  0.65315   
Concentration  0.0012602  0.0005232   2.409  0.03932 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 1.615836)

    Null deviance: 24.689  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 14.543  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 44.361

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> trout_model2<- lm(logit~Water + Concentration, data = trout_new)
> summary(trout_model2)

Call:
lm(formula = logit ~ Water + Concentration, data = trout_new)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.12774 -0.57066  0.08564  0.70799  1.99285 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -3.2888858  0.8145197  -4.038  0.00294 **
Water          0.3817345  0.8213712   0.465  0.65315   
Concentration  0.0012602  0.0005232   2.409  0.03932 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.271 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.411, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2801 
F-statistic:  3.14 on 2 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.09239
```

The coefficients from the linear regression of the log odds (logit transformation) is different to that of logistic regression. Can someone explain why they are different? Is there more to logistic regression that I'm overlooking? Does the difference lie in the Maximum Likelihood vs Least Squares functions?

If the log odds of a response equate to a linear combination of parameters as suggested by textbooks. How can I model this in R using the `lm()` function or is that not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three reasons come to mind.

1. Taking the expected value of a transformation need not equal that same transformation of an expected value. Jensen’s inequality is one result related to this.
2. You can do this when you have multiple events correspond to the same features, as you appear to have. For each value of concentration and the “water” indicator variable, you have multiple observations, some of which are successes and some of which are failures. Logistic regression need not operate on such data. It is totally possible, perhaps even more common, to have every success and failure correspond to a unique combination of features. Then you cannot calculate the log-odds, as the event either happened with (probability $1$) or did not happen (probability $0$). Dividing by zero and taking logarithms of zero is problematic.
3. Why should they be equal? The optimization procedures are totally different. One involves minimizing square loss (corresponding to maximum likelihood estimation for a Gaussian conditional distribution) while the other involves minimizing log loss (corresponding to maximum likelihood estimation for a binomial conditional distribution).

For that second one, consider how you would define the log-odds in a table like the one generated by the following code.

```
set.seed(2022) # soon will be time for a new seed value!
N <- 100
concentration <- runif(N, 0, 1)
water <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
total <- rep(1, N)
successes <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
d <- data.frame(
    concentration,
    water,
    total,
    successes
)
d
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I wouldn't be able to do a logit transformation on values of zero events. 
I'll have to learn more about the different maximum likelihood optimization procedures.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dave's answer, I think this has been already addressed in:
[What is the difference between logit-transformed linear regression, logistic regression, and a logistic mixed model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48485/what-is-the-difference-between-logit-transformed-linear-regression-logistic-reg)

My suggestion is to think on the experimental/sampling design. Since your data look indeed binomial, a GLM might in principle be more powerful and appropriate than a linear model ([Warton, D. I., & Hui, F. K. (2011). The arcsine is asinine: the analysis of proportions in ecology. Ecology, 92(1), 3-10](https://doi.org/10.1890/10-0340.1)).

However, given the repeated, discrete values of concentration, your data look like from a manipulative experiment (sensu [Hurlbert, S. H. (1984). Pseudoreplication and the design of ecological field experiments. Ecological monographs, 54(2), 187-211](https://doi.org/10.2307/1942661)). If this is case, to avoid pseudoreplication a linear model (with some transformation!) or a GLMM (i.e. generalized linear mixed model) might be preferable (see e.g. [Waller, B. M., Warmelink, L., Liebal, K., Micheletta, J., & Slocombe, K. E. (2013). Pseudoreplication: a widespread problem in primate communication research. Animal Behaviour, 86(2), 483-488](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.anbehav.2013.05.038); [Arnqvist, G. (2020). Mixed models offer no freedom from degrees of freedom. Trends in ecology & evolution, 35(4), 329-335](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tree.2019.12.004)).

Comment: Also related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122103/1569