# GEE and GLS. Are they similar?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, generalized-estimating-equations, generalized-least-squares

First of all there is another question about it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327929/is-gls-a-special-case-of-gee), but it has no answers unfortunately...And also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-to-use-generalized-estimating-equations-vs-mixed-effects-models), but it is more general about mixed models and GEE, while my question is more specific...

So, my question is simle but also very general: Are GEE and GLS the same model ?

For instance, if i run a model with gls() + AR(1) structure and a GEE +AR(1) structure, will these 2 correspond to the same model ?

And if not, why ? In which part do they differ ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure ? Because they talk about mixed models in general vs GEE...But my question is more specific about GLS ( no random parts ). And also, i do not have the reputation yet to comment there.... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use generalized estimating equations vs. mixed effects models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-to-use-generalized-estimating-equations-vs-mixed-effects-models)

Comment: i explained  myself in the previous comment....someone else also made the same comment which he probably deleted....

Answer (score 1):

In Section 13.2 of *Applied longitudinal analysis*, it says:

> For the case of linear models (i.e., marginal models with an identity link function), the generalized least squares (GLS) estimator of $\beta$ discussed in Chapter 4 can be considered a special case of the GEE approach.

### Reference

Fitzmaurice, Garrett M., Nan M. Laird, and James H. Ware. Applied longitudinal analysis. Vol. 998. John Wiley & Sons, 2012.