# How to choose between mixed effect and GEE

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations

my outcome variable is on patient discharge disposition, with three categories(1.home,2.nursing home 3. hospital)
my independent variable is based on hospital characteristics, eg bed (1. <500; 2.>500), location (1.rural; 2.urban area)
I don't have further patient-level characteristics. I want to look at on avearge the facility characteristics have impact on patient disposition.
what model should I choose? Thank you.

| patientID | facility ID | bed | location | discharge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: Does this answer your question:[When to use generalized estimating equations vs. mixed effects models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-to-use-generalized-estimating-equations-vs-mixed-effects-models)