# Can lack of main effect and lack of interaction be caused by the same confound?

Tags: anova, statistical-significance, confounding

Can the lack of main effect have the same underlying cause as the lack of interaction in 2-way ANOVA?

My results failed to reach significance for variables of gender and language. Is it possible that a confounding variable which affected language (and thus made it impossible for main effect of language to reach significance) has influenced the interaction in the same way? Or am I being lazy and not analysing my design deeply enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct; there is a link between main and interaction effects.

"For example, it's possible to have a non-significant interaction that is still substantial enough to make it look like you have main effects when you don't have main effects."

[How to interpret main effects when the interaction effect is not significant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31027/how-to-interpret-main-effects-when-the-interaction-effect-is-not-significant)