# How to interpret probabilities in logistic regression with interactions?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, interaction, logit

Transforming from logit to probabilities in logistic regression models facilitate the interpretation when terms are additive. But, what about interactions?

How can I interpret probabilities when terms include interactions between continuous predictors, just as the same way as interpreting logit relations?

Comment: or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate of those two combined. Not sure how to mark that. Maybe an answer referencing those two threads?

Comment: @PeterFlom I've seem that before, can't find an example right now, but can you edit the message like in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122417/332725 ?