# Comparing N-way joint frequency distributions of different subsets?

Tags: frequency, subset

Say I have binary variables:

- tall
- basketball player
- football player
- vegan
- programmer
- student

We are also given subsets of a population.

My objective is that I want find out what combination of variables best describes how a subset is significantly different that the rest of the population.

For example, say in the entire population of 1000 people there are only 5 people that are vegan, NOT tall, and are basketball players. And all 5 of those people belong to subset A with a count of 20 people. Intuitively I know that {vegan, NOT tall, and basketball players} are an interesting combination of variables that distinguishes subset A from the rest of the population.

What types of statistical analysis should I look to for doing this in a systematic way?

Answer (score 1):

This is not my area, but something like [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/logistic/info) may work well, providing [interpretable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/interpreting-interaction-terms-in-logit-regression-with-categorical-variables) coefficients. (For more than 2 subsets, there is [multi-class logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression).)

I believe there are [tricks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633403/how-to-automatically-include-all-2-way-interactions-in-a-glm-model-in-r) to specify the various [interaction terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)#Model_size). However including all of these is probably ill advised, in terms of model over-fitting and interpretability. You could start with no interactions, then explore incrementally adding 2-way ... k-way interactions.