# Interpretation of interaction term in R logit output

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, interpretation

I hope this is the right place for this question. I have the following logistic regression output (these are the coefficients in log odds, not AMEs):

[image]

This is from a logistic regression. The R command I used to create (3) is:

```r
logit_mint3_me = logitmfx(formula = mint ~ agen_sh_mint1 + 
    komm_sh_mint1 + female + same_kldb_3d_m + same_kldb_3d_f + 
    female*same_kldb_3d_m + (1-female)*same_kldb_3d_f, 
    data = joined_ds)
```

I am not sure as to how to interpret the coefficient for the interaction term. Is it missing the case where female = 0, or would in this case only the coefficient for "same_kldb_3d_f" be relevant. Is it to be interpreted to a "base category", as in, that the coefficient value for female:same_kldb_3d_m is equal to the log odds change when female goes from 0 to 1?

Could anyone provide me with the correct interpretation of this coefficient?

Comment: I think there are problems with your formula, the `1-female` doesn't work as you think,, maybe you need `I(1-female)` to assure that the minus sign is interpreted arithmetically and not formally.  Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/interpreting-interaction-terms-in-logit-regression-with-categorical-variables, does that answer your question? Also search this site, as there are many similar questions