# Interpretation of a regression where two variables predict a third variable individually but not when entered together

Tags: regression

I have a situation where two variables when entered into a regression model independently, both predict a third variable, but when I entered both those variables into the model together, neither one significantly predicts the third variable independently, but overall the model is significant.

In other words.

1st regression - A significantly predicts C

2nd regression - B significantly predcits C

3rd regression (both entered together):

- A does not significant predict C
- B does not significantly predict C
- Model overall is significant

What does this mean? Does it just mean they share too much variance (A also significantly predicts B)? How would I interpret this?

thanks

---

---

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Thanks, I think this may explain what is going on with my data well. However, this leads me to a follow-up question about mediation. As it is a different question, I will start it in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal.

See this question and answer

[Two negative main effects yet positive interaction effect?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80050/two-negative-main-effects-yet-positive-interaction-effect/80084#80084)

Similar, suppose, your $A$ is amount of hot water, $B$ is amount of cold water, $C$ is number of death for fish. Both $A$ and $B$ can contribute $C$ significantly, but adding both $A$ and $B$, $C$ may have no impact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that make sense. 
But is it always the case that a significant overall effect of a model is the result of an interaction when the individual predictors are not significant?